# list extracted from dataframe column recognized as string

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I have a `dataframe` with list in one column(or more than one column). My goal is to iterate through those lists in the `dataframe` column and to print the values in separate rows.

[image: dataframe]

The problem is that when I try to iterate through list which is in frameLen:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    for i in row['frameLen']:
        print(i)
```

I get some weird result :

```
[
8
0
,

8
0
,

8
0
,

8
0
,

8
0
,

8
0
]
```

It seems like my list is interpreted as string.

Could someone tell me why is that and what could I do to fix it?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do not using list within a col

How to fix it ?

```
import ast 
df['frameLen']=df['frameLen'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: How do you mean not to use list within column? Is there any other way to append multiple values to one dataframe column.
Actualy the strange thing is when I create dataframe with list in 'frameLen' column, and then grab that column, it is possible to iterate through list.
When I export it to .csv and then again import it, the list is recognize as string. Any idea why is this happening?